# Effeciently extend n number of lists together

Tags: python, list, extend

Say you have an infinite number of python lists.

How would you efficiently extend all of them together without manually writing out the extend function?

For instance,

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
.
.
.
ln = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]

# Not this
l1.extend(l2)
l1.extend(l3)
.
.
.
l1.extend(ln)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need `l1+l2+l3+..ln`

Comment: Yes, but how do you grab each of them assuming that each list has been individually defined?

Comment: You wouldn't define them all explicitly. You might instead put all the lists inside another list.

Comment: @Neel What you are looking for is not clear

Comment: There are almost 100 individually defined lists i.e l1, l2, l3, that are not within a list. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
list(chain(l1, l2, ..., ln)
#[1,2,3, ..., ln[n]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this could work. How would you chain each list item without manually typing them in?

Comment: Try a search for that question or ask a new one that’s more a different question I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can add them together [1,2,3] + [3,4,5], that's another way

If you have a bunch of variables like l1,l2,l3,l4,l5, you can do something like this:

```
for x in range (1,5): 
   new_list = new_list + eval('l' + str(x))
```

which would add lists together that aren't grouped into a list of lists.

Here's one that handles an inconsistent format without errors:

```
l1=[1,3]
l2=[4,5]
l3=[5,6]
n1=[2,3]
n5=[4,7]


new_list=[]
letters = ['l','n']
for items in letters:
    for x in range(0,6):
       try:
          new_list = new_list + eval(items + str(x))
       except: 
           continue
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you grab each of them assuming that each list has been individually defined?

Comment: updated with info on how to do that. As long as there is a good naming convention you can use eval and a for loop

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be close. Naming convention is not consistent though...

Comment: what kind of difference do you have? You can use try: except: for those weird cases where you have l1 - l10, then n1-20, so when it doesn't find l11, it still works. Does that make sense?

Comment: i updated with how to deal with inconsistent data, maybe that will help?

Comment: I have long tail words. I'm trying to make yours work with regex.

Comment: Neel, can i help more, i'm pretty good with regex, i'd really like to put some effort into answering your question so i can get more points, i bumped your question up, it's a fun problem you have that i've had before, which is why i'm interested in it

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
l3  = [10,11,12,13]
y = [l2,l3]

[l1.extend(x) for x in y] 
print(l1)

Out[33]:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

updated

```
 y = ['l{}'.format(y) for y in range(0,100)] # to get all 100 list, l1,l2,l3...l100
 [l1.extend(eval(x)) for x in y]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have nearly 100 individually defined lists. I don't think individually placing them in list y personally is efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Similar to oppressionslayer solution, that factors in variations in variables name. Close, but no joy yet.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something to generate your infinite series of lists, like:

```
def feeder(n):
    while True:
        yield[x for x in range(n)]
```

and then a function to link one to the next forever:

```
def extender(n):
    a = feeder(n)
    ln = []
    while True:
        ln += next(a)
```

Then, `>>> extender(100)` fills up memory fairly quickly.
[Edit change lists as per question]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify the role of extender? Reason is because I don't see it return some kind of result?

Comment: As written nothing is ever returned; the line ```a = feeder(n)``` creates a generator that makes lists of length n indefinitely. If you wanted a list of 100 lists, then replace ```while True:``` with ```for x in range(100)``` and then have the final line in the function be ```return ln```.